# Mac vs. Windows Browser Font Height Rendering Issue

Tags: windows, macos, browser, font-face

I'm using a custom font and the @font-face tag.  In Windows, everything looks great, regardless of whether it's Firefox, Chrome, or IE.

On Mac, it's a different story.  For some reason, the Mac font renderer thinks the font is a lot shorter than it is.

For example, consider this test code ([live example here](http://cdmckay.org/files/font-test/test.html)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />        
        <title>Webble</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        @font-face
        {
            font-family: "Bubbleboy 2";
            src: url("bubbleboy-2.ttf") format('truetype');         
        }

        body
        {
            font-family: "Bubbleboy 2";
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        div
        {
            background-color: maroon;
            color: yellow;
            height: 100px;
            line-height: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open it on Windows Firefox and on Mac Firefox.  Use your mouse to select it.

On Windows, you'll notice it fully selects the font.

On Mac, it only selects about half the font.  If you look at what it is selecting, you'll see that that part has been centered, instead of the full height of the font.

Is there anyway to fix this rather large discrepancy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font's ascent is too small. The Windows browsers (and Mac Safari, too, in my testing) just throw out the ascent value as incorrect, whereas Firefox and Opera on the Mac accept it.

The easiest way to fix this is with ttx, part of [FontTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/).

Use it like this:

```
% ttx bubbleboy-2.ttf
[...]
% edit bubbleboy-2.ttx
```

Change the ascent value to 1100 (or whatever works for you):

```
  <hhea>
    <tableVersion value="1.0"/>
    <ascent value="1100"/>
```

Then reconstitute the font:

```
% ttx bubbleboy-2.ttx 
Compiling "bubbleboy-2.ttx" to "bubbleboy-2#1.ttf"...
[...]
```

This new font should be fixed; you can check by opening it in Font Book.

If you want a more visual picture of the problem, try [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/), though be warned its interface is rather baroque.   Once you've opened the font, double-click a capital letter; you'll see a horizontal line bisecting the glyph.  This is the (wrong) ascent.  You can fix the ascent in Element > Font Info, then click General.  Uncheck "Scale Outlines" or the ascent will be bigger but still wrong. :-)

However, to modify the font, I would recommend ttx over FontForge for small changes like this because it's less likely to destroy what it doesn't understand.

Comment: Hmmm, now some new weirdness: the font resulting from editing the TTX files works everywhere except Chrome for Windows, where it seems not to accept it.

Comment: Hmm interesting.  If I convert a font to TTX and back to TTF without editing anything, it still doesn't work on Chrome for Windows.  Must be an issue with TTX, I'll give FontForge a go.

Comment: Gah, that's annoying, I've never had any problems with ttx.  You might report it to the Letteror folks.

Comment: Found a solution: edit the font with TTX, convert back to TTF, then open it in FontForge and re-save it.  Then it works everywhere :)

Comment: Editing hhea `ascent` will adjust the ascent for iOS/macOS; for Windows, edit the `winAscent` or `usWinAscent` property. Here is a good listing of which properties are used by each operating system: https://glyphsapp.com/tutorials/vertical-metrics

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my font by uploading the TTF version to [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and selecting the "Expert" option and then keeping all default options. The one that fixes it I believe is "Fix Vertical Metrics."

Now the font line height renders the same on MAC and PC. Good luck

Answer (score -3):

Actually Windows is the culprit. Windows ClearType font renderer actually hammers the font's shape into pixel boundaries to make it "clearer" whereas Mac OS doesn't touch the shape of the font (which I very much *prefer*). This often leads to "taller" or "thinner" glyphs on screen, whereas on Mac OS you get a true representation of the font as the designer intended.

Here's an article by Jeff Atwood explaining the differences. In any case, you're not going to be able to get around it.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html

Comment: Ugh... serious?  What a pain.  I guess I'll have to come up with some CSS hacks :(

Comment: Unfortunately the way the font is rendered is out of the web designer's control, at least until you bite the bullet and use images or maybe give server rendered title images.

Comment: This isn't correct at all; the pixel grid changes are tiny compared to nearly half the height of the characters as described here. The problem is just a buggy font. Please see my answer.

Comment: Mac OS is definitely making a mistake here. Given a font with a similar bug, if you set a line-height the same height as the parent element it will correctly center on Windows, whereas it'll be off on Mac. Definitely a bug, not a feature.