# Why is there a @font-face difference in line-height on Windows and Mac OS X?

Tags: html, macos, font-face, css

I have been searching for an answer for this for an hour now with no luck.

I am centering text vertically inside the box using the "line-height" CSS property. This is working fine with standard safe fonts and also works fine for ""@font-face"" font embedding on Windows.

On the Mac however, there is a problem with this centering using "@font-face". See: http://cl.ly/QBlE/o

I don't know what to do with this. The only way to fix this to use different line-height for Mac. But as far as I know this is not possible without JavaScript or server side programming and does not seem to be the proper solution for me.

Example (blue box at the top):

```
#header .login {
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:11px 9px 0 9px;
    float:right;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff;
    background:url(../img/header-login.png);
    width:118px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Helvetica55', Sans-Serif;
}
```

Comment: i have the same issue, need help on this.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the other methods for vertically centered text?  Must it be centered using line-height?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using different line heights, try using the `font-size-adjust` property with a value of `auto`.

From the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop):

> In situations where font fallback occurs, fallback fonts may not share the same aspect ratio as the desired font family and will thus appear less readable. The font-size-adjust property is a way to preserve the readability of text when font fallback occurs. It does this by adjusting the font-size so that the x-height is the same regardless of the font used.

Comment: Currently only supported by Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

First, try setting the line-height from px to em.

If that doesn't work, then it could be caused by default styles that are different for each browser. Those default styles could be messing with your styles. So try to use a reset.css in your page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most probably lies in the used font. Each font has its own metrics and when not optimized properly they can differ from one platform to another. See http://blog.typekit.com/2010/07/14/font-metrics-and-vertical-space-in-css/ for a better explanation of this.

You could try to alter the font yourself using a tool like http://fontforge.org/. This isn't easy though and takes some trial and error to get it right. It may also violate the license of the font you're using.

My advice: choose a font that is better optimized for use on the web. Take any font from Typekit or the like and i bet you get more consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'vertical-align:' may help,

please check this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/YZUTM/38/)

this will explain the difference, I think every browser have different default value,

here I have created 4 different span tag to show the top, middle, bottom, and default(unassigned) value of the vertical align value,

Please change values if that helps,

as you are using images in the button, please verify the image are set with 0 0
i.e `background:url(../img/header-login.png) no-repeat 0 0;`

this will render the image from the 0 left and 0 top that will help you idnetify if and image is not properly generated..

Please reply if problem not solved..

Answer (score 0):

From my experience for multi browser and multi platform websites you should really drop the pixels in fonts and start using ems.

Here's a useful convertion table tool:

http://pxtoem.com/

Let me know if it still happens using em. Keep in mind also that different fonts have different behaviors and the default (base) size may differ too. If you want to make sure it is exactly the same size, appart from using 'em' you should also use an openType font and embbed it into your CSS, having exactly the same font and size in any screen or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems may render fonts different ways. One can start from bottom and other can start from top as their algorithm different. If the problem was CSS, it wouldn't be resolved by another type of font.

I found another question similiar to your one, you can check if it works for your situation:
[Mac vs. Windows Browser Font Height Rendering Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854028/mac-vs-windows-browser-font-height-rendering-issue)